# Transform a collection of key-value pairs into a dictionary that lists the values?

Tags: python, data-manipulation

I'm confident there's a succinct pythonic way to convert:

```
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 4)]
```

Into:

```
{'a':[1, 2], 'b':[4]}
```

I've tried various combinations of `zip`, `dict`, and `itertools.groupby` and I can't get my head round how to do this.

Comment: `d = defaultdict(list); for key, val in l: d[key].append(val)`. Surely you could have found e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5378231/3001761?

Comment: @jonrsharpe wow,  how did I  not find that? I don't think mobile helps.