# Convert a pair of list objects into dictionary with duplicates included

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I can club two lists into a dictionary as below -

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = ['a','b','c','d']
dct = dict(zip(list1, list2))
print(dct)
```

Result,

```
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}
```

However with duplicates as below,

```
list3 = [1,2,3,3,4,4]
list4 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
dct_ = dict(zip(list1, list2))
print(dct)
```

I get,

```
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}
```

What should i do to consider the duplicates in my list as individual keys in my resulting dictionary?

I am expecting results as below -

```
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e', 4: 'f'}
```

Comment: This is not possible with a `dict`. A key can appear at most once.

Comment: @Michael Butscher is there any other way i can implement this(mapping between the lists irrespective of the duplicates in the lists)? I need to use this in my application.

Comment: @Rohit see YOLO's answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [list to dictionary conversion with multiple values per key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378231/list-to-dictionary-conversion-with-multiple-values-per-key)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead you can create the dictionary with values as list:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

for k,v in zip(list3, list4):
    d[k].append(v)

defaultdict(list, {1: ['a'], 2: ['b'], 3: ['c', 'd'], 4: ['e', 'f']})
```

Comment: `d[k].append(v)` would be better. As is, you replace the list with a fresh one each time, that's too much copying.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have duplicate keys in a dictionary. However, you can have multiple values(a list) mapped to each key.

An easy way to do this is with [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
list3 = [1,2,3,3,4,4]
list4 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']

d = {}
for x, y in zip(list3, list4):
    d.setdefault(x, []).append(y)

print(d)
# {1: ['a'], 2: ['b'], 3: ['c', 'd'], 4: ['e', 'f']}
```

The other option is to use a [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), as shown in @YOLO's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53688658/convert-a-pair-of-list-objects-into-dictionary-with-duplicates-included/53688679#53688679).