# Python dictionary append to key?

Tags: python, dictionary, append

I have been doing some reading and I think the correct solution to what I am trying to achieve is a dictionary...

I have been playing and looking at examples and they seem the way to go. I am having a problem though. While I can create a key and set its value without issues, I am unable to add values to an existing key.

Here is what I am trying

```
dict = {}
...
if key not in dict:
   dict[key] = value
else:
   dict[key].append(value)
```

It gives me...

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

The if else statement is firing correctly if I use prints.
The key is added if it does not exist.
The error only occurs on the append line.

What I expect is a list of values per key.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: You do this when the dict values are already lists. Consider using defaultdict(list). Or you could have done dict[key] = [value,] in the initial assignment.

Comment: just change your initial set to "dict[key] = [value]"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [list to dictionary conversion with multiple values per key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378231/list-to-dictionary-conversion-with-multiple-values-per-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to insert your initial key as a list with one element:

```
dict = {}
...
if key not in dict:
   dict[key]=[value]
else:
   dict[key].append(value)
```

this works fine:

```
dict={}
dict["key"]=[1]
dict["key"].append(2)
dict 

{'key': [1, 2]}
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @kenny

All you have to do is

```py
from collections import defaultdict

dic = defaultdict(list)

# it creates a list if the key is not in dictionary automatically
dic[key].append(value)
```