# Python: Add elements to set value in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, set, addition

I have a problem adding a value to a set which is a value in a dictionary. I have to use sets as values not list or anything else. I have seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199171/append-multiple-values-for-one-key-in-python-dictionary) but it does not full ansver me.

```
from collections import defaultdict
datoteka = open("vzorec.list","rt")
slovar = defaultdict(set)

for vrstica in datoteka:
    seznam = vrstica.split("\t")
    naslov = seznam[0]
    beseda = seznam[len(seznam)-1]
    beseda = beseda.strip()
    naslov2 = ""
    for crka in naslov:
        if crka == "(":
            break
        else:
            naslov2 = naslov2 + crka
    naslov = naslov2.lstrip('"')

    if naslov not in slovar:
        slovar[naslov] = set(beseda)

    elif naslov in slovar:
        slovar[naslov] = slovar[naslov].add(beseda)



print(slovar)
```

I get an error that a string type does not have an add function. But why does python not understand that I want to have sets as values. I even used the `defaultdict`

Comment: @hochl: Actually I think using a `defaultdict` is more elegant.

Comment: @hochl -- `defaultdict` is definitely more elegant (and probably more efficient) as it doesn't create an unnecessary set at every iteration through the loop.

Answer (score 8):

You just want:

```
slovar[naslov].add(beseda)
```

instead of:

```
if naslov not in slovar:
    slovar[naslov] = set(beseda) # set of characters in beseda string ???

elif naslov in slovar:
    slovar[naslov] = slovar[naslov].add(beseda) # add to the set, returns None ???
```

This works because with a `defaultdict`, if the key isn't present, it adds an empty set as the value to that particular key and returns it empty set.  So, the first time around, `slovar[naslov]` returns an empty set which you then `.add(beseda)`.

Comment: If `beseda` is a string, then `set(beseda)` will return a set of individual characters, while `slovar[naslov].add(beseda)` will insert a full string into an existing set. One of these two behaviors is probably not desired here.

Comment: Yep, probably OP means either `set((besada,))` or `.extend(beseda)`

Comment: Seeing that "naslov" means "address" and "slovar" means "dictionary" and "beseda" means "word", I think that the first one is more likely.

Comment: @NiklasB.  -- It looks like we're both using google translate.  Anyway, my money's on the first one too.  I don't know why I said second in my previous comment (I'll blame it on a bit-flip in my brain)...

Answer (score 6):

Python understands fine :). You have a bug in your code.

`set.add` mutates the set and returns `None`, so you've discarded your set and set the key to `None`. You just want to do `slovar[naslov].add(beseda)` whether `naslov` is or isn't in the set, and not care about the return value.

I don't see how a string would be getting in there, so if that doesn't solve your issue, you need to paste a full traceback.

Comment: Thank you very much guys!
How could I have not seen it.
I hope it helps someone else.