# Sorting identical keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started learning python and was wondering if its possible to pair two identical keys?

example:

```
my_dict= {1:a,3:b,1:c}
```

and I want to make a new dict, something like this:

```
new_dict= {1:{a,c},3:{b}}
```

thanks for the help

Comment: The original dict is illegal (try it) but your required outcome is possible. You can make each dict entry a list and have it contain the values you want.

Comment: You should read about hashing. And how it makes identical keys impossible.

Comment: You cannot have duplicate keys in a dictionary in the first place.

Comment: Your input would need to be different something like `[(1,'a'),(3,'b'),(1,'c')]` and your output `{1: ['a','c'], 3: ['b']}`.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199171/append-multiple-values-for-one-key-in-python-dictionary) for ideas on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have identical keys, that is the definition of dictionary. As soon as you add again the same key, the previous entry is deleted

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have repeated dictionary keys in python.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you're trying to combine the two dictionaries. Given that you cannot have same keys in a dictionary, I'll suppose you have two distinct dictionaries you'd like to combine to obtain your combination.

Ex:

```
dic1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

dic2 = {'c': 4, 'd': 5, 'e': 6}
```

And the combination would produce:

{'a': {1}, 'b': {2}, 'c':{3, 4}, 'd': {4}, 'e': {6}}

You could use this Example:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict

dic1 = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
dic2 = {'C': 4, 'D': 5, 'E': 6}

dic = defaultdict(set)

for k, v in chain(dic1.items(), dic2.items()):
    dic[k].add(v)

print(dict(dic))
```

Something to note:

- 'dic' is not exactly a dict(), it's of type 'defaultdict', but you can do dict(dic) to make it so.
- You could instead of using set, use list in the defaultdict() argument and have a dictionary as so:

  {'a': [1], 'b': [2], 'c':[3, 4], 'd': [4], 'e': [6]}

  But to do so, dic[k].append(v) would be used in the for loop. You add items to sets, append to lists.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries in Python, or any hash-able type for that matter, will not allow duplicate keys. If two duplicate keys are found in a dictionary, the key farthest in the dictionary will be persevered. This behavior can be obsevered first hand:

```
>>> my_dict= {1:'a',3:'b',1:'c'}
>>> my_dict
{1: 'c', 3: 'b'}
>>> my_dict= {1:'c',3:'b',1:'a'}
>>> my_dict
{1: 'a', 3: 'b'}
>>>
```

The Python documentation for `dict()`s touches on this matter:

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value pairs, **with the requirement that the keys are unique** (within one dictionary).[...].

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>