# key error when building dict with arrays

Tags: python, dictionary, multidimensional-array, arcpy

I am trying to build two dicts, one with even street values and one with odd street values. Each street has a Ref_ID, and I want each dict to use these values as the keys and their corresponding sequence numbers as the values.

I saw a former post to make a dict with an array as the values:
[append multiple values for one key in Python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199171/append-multiple-values-for-one-key-in-python-dictionary)

I tried doing this in my code although I think the conditionals for even and odd as well as using an arcpy.SearchCursor is adding some complexity to the code:

```
import arcpy

#service location layer
fc = r"J:\Workspace\FAN3 sequencing3\gisdb\layers.gdb\Rts_239_241_314_GoLive"

# create variables

f1 = "Route"
f2 = "Ref_ID"
f3 = "Sequence"
f4 = "Street_Number"

# create containers

rSet = set()
eLinks = dict()
oLinks = dict()

# make a route list

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, f1) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        rSet.add(row[0])
    del row

# list of even side street sequences
eItems = []
eCheckStreet = []

# list of odd side street sequences
oItems = []
oCheckStreet = []

# make two dicts, one with links as keys holding sequence values for the even side of the street
# the other for the odd side of the street

for route in rSet:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, [f2,f3,f4]) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row[2] != '0' and int(row[2]) % 2 == 0:
                if row[0] in eLinks:
                    eLinks[str(row[0])].append(row[1])
                else:
                    eLinks[str(row[0])] = [row[0]]
            elif row[2] != '0' and int(row[2]) % 2 != 0:
                if row[0] in eLinks:
                    oLinks[str(row[0])].append(row[1])
                else:
                    oLinks[str(row[0])] = [row[0]]
        del row

print eLinks, oLinks
```

The output is the Ref_ID as both the key and the value. I've tried changing the index just to see if I'd getting soemthing different but it's still the same. I also tried converting if str(row[0]) in eLinks but to no avail.

Comment: I don't know if this will fix the problem, but after `elif` your `if` is looking for `row[0]` in `eLinks`, while it should probably look in `oLinks`. That will always return `False`. You might want to make both `eLinks` and `oLinks` `defaultdict(list)`, so that you don't have to initialize manually (i.e. you can skip the nested `if`s).

Comment: Thanks Mikk for pointing out the oLinks typo. I changed that and used collections but got the same result. I then got rid of the nested if and it worked like a charm. Go ahead and post the answer and I'll check it off. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I thuink you should answer your own question, I'm not 100% sure about what you did :-)

Comment: I used the collections.defaultdict(list) and got rid of the nested if, as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is likely in the nested `if` and how those conditions interplay with each other. You don't have to take on your shoulders the responsibility of standard key checks on your dictionary: there's a built-in data structure for your that does that: `collections.defaultdict`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

```
import arcpy
from collections import defaultdict

#service location layer
fc = r"J:\Workspace\FAN3 sequencing3\gisdb\layers.gdb\Rts_239_241_314_GoLive"

# create variables

f1 = "Route"
f2 = "Ref_ID"
f3 = "Sequence"
f4 = "Street_Number"

# create containers

rSet = set()
eLinks = defaultdict(list)
oLinks = defaultdict(list)

# make a route list

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, f1) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        rSet.add(row[0])
    del row


# make two dicts, one with links as keys holding sequence values for the even side of the street
# the other for the odd side of the street

for route in rSet:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, [f2,f3,f4]) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row[2] != '0' and int(row[2]) % 2 == 0:
                eLinks[str(row[0])].append(row[1])
            elif row[2] != '0' and int(row[2]) % 2 != 0:
                oLinks[str(row[0])].append(row[1])
        del row
print eLinks, oLinks
```