# Filter list based on the element in nested list at specific index

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list of list containing:

```
[['4.2','3.4','G'],['2.4','1.2','H'],['8.7','5.4','G']]
```

and i want to obtain the value from the list of list by **referring to the alphabet in the third section** of every list inside the list of list.

example, I want python to print the element **represented by letter 'G'** for every item in the list of list.

```
output = [4.2,3.4]
         [8.7,5.4]
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
L = [['4.2','3.4','G'],['2.4','1.2','H'],['8.7','5.4','G']]
newList = []

for line in L:
    if line[0][2] == 'G'
        newList.append([float(i) for i in line[0:2]])
print(newList)
```

my error would be on line 5 as I'm not sure if i am able to do it this way. Regards.

Comment: Why do you compare with `'house'` in the if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues in your code,

```
1. line = ['4.2', '3.4', 'G'] for 1st iteration
hence to check for 'G', look out for line[2] == 'G' instead of line[0][3] == 'G'
2. use 'G' instead off 'house'.

>>> for line in L:
...   if line[2] == 'G':
...     newList.append([float(i) for i in line[0:2]])
... 
>>> newList
[[4.2, 3.4], [8.7, 5.4]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple list comprehension:

```
L = [['4.2','3.4','G'],['2.4','1.2','H'],['8.7','5.4','G']]
newList = [l[0:2] for l in L if l[2] == 'G']

print(newList)
```

The output:

```
[['4.2', '3.4'], ['8.7', '5.4']]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), as a multi-value dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for x in L:
    d[x[2]].append(x[:2])
```

Now you can use `d['G']` to get what you wanted, but also `d['H']` to get the result for `'H'`!

Edit: Source [*append multiple values for one key in Python dictionary*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3199196/3858507)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a dictionary by iterating the list of lists.

```
lst = [['4.2','3.4','G'],['2.4','1.2','H'],['8.7','5.4','G']]
dict1 = {}

for l in lst:
    if l[2] in dict1.keys():
        dict1[l[2]].append(l[0:2])
    else:
        dict1[l[2]] = [l[0:2]]
        print l[0:2]

print dict1['G']
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create a function to return sub-lists based on the element using an *list comprehension* expression along with the usage of [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) as:

```
def get_element_by_alpha(alpha, data_list):
    #        v map returns generator object in Python 3.x,hence type-cast to `list`
    return [list(map(float, s[:2])) for s in data_list if s[2]==alpha]
    #                 ^ type-cast the number string to `float` type
```

Sample Runs:

```
>>> my_list = [['4.2','3.4','G'],['2.4','1.2','H'],['8.7','5.4','G']]

>>> get_element_by_alpha('G', my_list)
[[4.2, 3.4], [8.7, 5.4]]

>>> get_element_by_alpha('H', my_list)
[[2.4, 1.2]]

>>> get_element_by_alpha('A', my_list)  # 'A' not in the list
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension will do this:

```
newList = [[float(j) for j in i[:-1]] for i in L if i[2]=='G']
```

Answer (score 0):

**@Electric your edited code.**

```
L = [['4.2','3.4','G'],['2.4','1.2','H'],['8.7','5.4','G']]
newList = []

# line = ['4.2','3.4','G']
for line in L:
    if line[2] == 'G': # ':' was missing.
        newList.append(line[:2]) # line[:2] => ['4.2','3.4']
print(newList)
```