# How to remove a list item from another list based on an element's string

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
watchlist = [['NSE:SHIL',1],['NSE:SOLARA',1],['NSE:LINCOLN',1],['NSE:KITEX',1],['NSE:PPL',1],['NSE:PHILIPCARB',1],['NSE:SARLAPOLY',1],['NSE:PANAMAPET',1],['NSE:RPSGVENT',1]]
```

I want to remove the element list which contains the string 'SOLARA'. New watchlist should be like this:

```
watchlist = [['NSE:SHIL',1],['NSE:LINCOLN',1],['NSE:KITEX',1],['NSE:PPL',1],['NSE:PHILIPCARB',1],['NSE:SARLAPOLY',1],['NSE:PANAMAPET',1],['NSE:RPSGVENT',1]]
```

How do I do that?

thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter list based on the element in nested list at specific index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557170/filter-list-based-on-the-element-in-nested-list-at-specific-index) i.e. `watchlist = [sub for sub in watchlist if "SOLARA" not in sub[0]]`

Comment: Have you tried **anything at all**? What exactly is the problem you are encountering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it:

```
watchlist = [['NSE:SHIL',1],['NSE:SOLARA',1],['NSE:LINCOLN',1],['NSE:KITEX',1],['NSE:PPL',1],['NSE:PHILIPCARB',1],['NSE:SARLAPOLY',1],['NSE:PANAMAPET',1],['NSE:RPSGVENT',1]]

watchlist = [e for e in watchlist if not 'SOLARA' in e[0]]

print(watchlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove ***the first*** sublist which contains the string. If that is your case(There is only one item that has `'SOLARA'` inside), there is no need to iterate over every single item in the list using list comprehension, as soon as you find it, delete it and break the loop:

```
for i, lst in enumerate(watchlist):
    if 'SOLARA' in lst[0]:
        del watchlist[i]
        break
```

output :

```
[['NSE:SHIL', 1], ['NSE:LINCOLN', 1], ['NSE:KITEX', 1], ['NSE:PPL', 1], ['NSE:PHILIPCARB', 1], ['NSE:SARLAPOLY', 1], ['NSE:PANAMAPET', 1], ['NSE:RPSGVENT', 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
watchlist = [['NSE:SHIL',1],['NSE:SOLARA',1],['NSE:LINCOLN',1],['NSE:KITEX',1],['NSE:PPL',1],['NSE:PHILIPCARB',1],['NSE:SARLAPOLY',1],['NSE:PANAMAPET',1],['NSE:RPSGVENT',1]]
new_watchlist = [ele for ele in watchlist if 'SOLARA' not in ele[0]]

print(new_watchlist)
```

Output:

```
[['NSE:SHIL', 1], ['NSE:LINCOLN', 1], ['NSE:KITEX', 1], ['NSE:PPL', 1], ['NSE:PHILIPCARB', 1], ['NSE:SARLAPOLY', 1], ['NSE:PANAMAPET', 1], ['NSE:RPSGVENT', 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick :

```
watchlist = [['NSE:SHIL',1],['NSE:SOLARA',1],['NSE:LINCOLN',1],['NSE:KITEX',1],['NSE:PPL',1],['NSE:PHILIPCARB',1],['NSE:SARLAPOLY',1],['NSE:PANAMAPET',1],['NSE:RPSGVENT',1]]
filter_string = "SOLARA"
filtered_watchlist = [i for i in watchlist if filter_string not in i[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function:

```
watchlist = list(filter(lambda x: 'SOLARA' not in x[0], watchlist))
```