# Search for value in twodimensional list, get value

Tags: python, list

Sure totally easy for you:
How to get 'Fred' from the search ?

```
list = [[123, 'Fred'],[234234, 'Martha'],[89182038,'Adam']]
true_or_not = any(123 in sublist for sublist in list)
if true_or_not == True:
  name= ???
```

Comment: Don't use `any`, filter it - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43557214/2823755

Answer (score 1):

You could convert your nested list to a dict and look up the name by ID

```py
nested = [[123, 'Fred'],[234234, 'Martha'],[89182038,'Adam']]
users = {l[0]: l[1] for l in nested}
print(users[123])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Fred
```

This is assuming all ID's are unique

Comment: search_for = str(dataset[i][1]) ----   
print(users[search_for])<----- doesn't work, need to quote the variable, because "123", "234234", "89182038" and so on are strings, how to do that?
print(users['search_for']) <---- obviously doesn't work---print(users["123"])<--- this works, but need variable inside the brackets

Comment: your example doesnt show them as strings......... if you have the string in a variable just use that variable as the key

Answer (score 1):

A slight improvement to Chris answer:

```
nested = [[123, 'Fred'], [234234, 'Martha'], [89182038,'Adam']]
users = {id_: name for id_, name in nested}
print(users[123])
```

I think this makes it more clear how dict is constructed from list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `next()`:

```py
lst = [[123, "Fred"], [234234, "Martha"], [89182038, "Adam"]]

print(next(name for i, name in lst if i == 123))
```

Prints:

```
Fred
```

---

You can also specify default value in case `123` is not found:

```py
print(next((name for i, name in lst if i == 123), None))  # returns None if 123 is not found
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan doing it once maybe it is not necessary to transform to dict.

```
nested = [[123, 'Fred'], [234234, 'Martha'],[89182038,'Adam']]
[name for id_, name in nested if id_ == 123][0]
# Fred
```