# Matching value from CSV column to dictionary - python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary that contains company name and the related Better Business Bureau link that accompanies that company. I also have a CSV file that has the BBB link attached to the phone number(s) for those companies. I need to somehow combine the two based on the BBB link that is associated with the company name.

My ultimate end goal is to have a dataframe that contains:

Company Name, Link, Phone Number(s)

DICTIONARY:

```
{'A. G. Builders, Inc.': 'https://www.bbb.org/us/nc/durham/profile/home-builders/ag-builders-inc-0593-6037923', 'A. R. Russell': 'https://www.bbb.org/us/nc/raleigh/profile/general-contractor/russell-l-judy-builder-inc-0593-90082691', 'A. R. Russell Builders, Inc.': 'https://www.bbb.org/us/nc/raleigh/profile/general-contractor/russell-l-judy-builder-inc-0593-90082691', 'A.C.A. Enterprises, LLC': 'https://www.bbb.org/us/fl/ponce-de-leon/profile/building-contractors/aca-enterprises-llc-0683-90029401', 'A.D. Myers Builders, LLC': 'https://www.bbb.org/us/nc/charlotte/profile/general-contractor/meyer-builders-llc-0473-219405', 'ABS Construction Group': 'https://www.bbb.org/us/nc/newport/profile/general-contractor/ab-building-remodeling-llc-0593-90293532', 'Absolute Construction Group, LLC': 'https://www.bbb.org/us/nc/durham/profile/home-improvement/absolute-construction-group-llc-0593-90282628'}
```

CODE:

```
phone_list = [] 
url_with_phone = []

def phone_numbers():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    for url in url_list: #Looping through the list of the BBB links
        print(url) #Print the URL currently on
        driver.get(url)
        sleep(randint(4,6))
        phone = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("dtm-phone") #FINDS Phone num
        sleep(randint(4,8))
        print('looking for number')
        for p in phone:
            results = (p.text)
            print(results)
            sleep(randint(3,5))
            phone_list.append(results) # add phone number to phone_list
            sleep(randint(5,9))
            url_with_phone.append(url) #adds URL when phone num is found to match up with phone num

phone_numbers()
```

CSV OUTPUT OF LINKS & PHONE NUMBERS:

```
URL Searched,Phone Numbers
https://www.bbb.org/us/nc/durham/profile/home-builders/ag-builders-inc-0593-6037923,(919) 384-7005
https://www.bbb.org/us/nc/raleigh/profile/general-contractor/russell-l-judy-builder-inc-0593-90082691,(919) 625-7841
https://www.bbb.org/us/nc/raleigh/profile/general-contractor/russell-l-judy-builder-inc-0593-90082691,(919) 625-7841
https://www.bbb.org/us/fl/ponce-de-leon/profile/building-contractors/aca-enterprises-llc-0683-90029401,(850) 248-0597
https://www.bbb.org/us/fl/ponce-de-leon/profile/building-contractors/aca-enterprises-llc-0683-90029401,(850) 527-1767
https://www.bbb.org/us/nc/charlotte/profile/general-contractor/meyer-builders-llc-0473-219405,(704) 737-8409
```

For example, the first result in the CSV file belongs to AG Home Builders, is there a way I can add the key from the dictionary (Company Name) to the CSV based on matching the value?

I would want to add the company name to the CSV. What would be the best way to do this? I have read the following links to try and come up with my own results, but haven't had any luck  trying the solutions on my own. ([append multiple values for one key in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199171/append-multiple-values-for-one-key-in-a-dictionary), [list to dictionary conversion with multiple values per key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378231/list-to-dictionary-conversion-with-multiple-values-per-key))

Comment: Is `aca-enterprises-llc` a company name?

Comment: Yes, it is. Is there something specific about that i should be aware of?

Comment: Should the numbers be included in the names?

Comment: The numbers in the weblink should not be included. The names should match the name in the dictionary. For exmaple:

'A.C.A. Enterprises, LLC': 'https://www.bbb.org/us/fl/ponce-de-leon/profile/building-contractors/aca-enterprises-llc-0683-90029401' would have two entries [(850) 248-0597, (850) 527-1767 ]

Both of those numbers belong to ACA Enterprises LLC

Comment: Is my answer what you're looking for?

Comment: why are you using selenium? you can do this with requests i think you could simply use `defaultdict `with list from the collections module

Comment: @Datanovice, valid question, I think I was just flowing off the code I had written to gather the links from google. I could have done this in requests. I am no familiar with `defaultdict` from the collections module.

Comment: @AnnZen, yes it appears that will work! I figured extracting the names from the links would be an option.

Comment: @AnnZen, i tried your solution in my code and it returned empty lists. I am thinking I will need to get educated on the defaultdict or regex more as I didnt include all results here as the post was too long. I greatly appreciate your time and explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can use `re` to extract all the business names from the string:

```
import re

a = '''URL Searched,Phone Numbers
https://www.bbb.org/us/nc/durham/profile/home-builders/ag-builders-inc-0593-6037923,(919) 384-7005
https://www.bbb.org/us/nc/raleigh/profile/general-contractor/russell-l-judy-builder-inc-0593-90082691,(919) 625-7841
https://www.bbb.org/us/nc/raleigh/profile/general-contractor/russell-l-judy-builder-inc-0593-90082691,(919) 625-7841
https://www.bbb.org/us/fl/ponce-de-leon/profile/building-contractors/aca-enterprises-llc-0683-90029401,(850) 248-0597
https://www.bbb.org/us/fl/ponce-de-leon/profile/building-contractors/aca-enterprises-llc-0683-90029401,(850) 527-1767
https://www.bbb.org/us/nc/charlotte/profile/general-contractor/meyer-builders-llc-0473-219405,(704) 737-8409'''

print([re.findall('.*c(?=\-\d)',n.split('/')[-1])[0] for n in a.split('\n')[1:]])
```

Output:

```
['ag-builders-inc',
 'russell-l-judy-builder-inc',
 'russell-l-judy-builder-inc',
 'aca-enterprises-llc',
 'aca-enterprises-llc',
 'meyer-builders-llc']
```

---

For a prettier presentation:

```
print([re.findall('.*c(?=\-\d)',n.split('/')[-1])[0].replace('-',' ').title() for n in a.split('\n')[1:]])
```

Output:

```
['Ag Builders Inc',
 'Russell L Judy Builder Inc',
 'Russell L Judy Builder Inc',
 'Aca Enterprises Llc',
 'Aca Enterprises Llc',
 'Meyer Builders Llc']
```

#### UPDATE:

```
import re

a = '''URL Searched,Phone Numbers
https://www.bbb.org/us/nc/durham/profile/home-builders/ag-builders-inc-0593-6037923,(919) 384-7005
https://www.bbb.org/us/nc/raleigh/profile/general-contractor/russell-l-judy-builder-inc-0593-90082691,(919) 625-7841
https://www.bbb.org/us/nc/raleigh/profile/general-contractor/russell-l-judy-builder-inc-0593-90082691,(919) 625-7841
https://www.bbb.org/us/fl/ponce-de-leon/profile/building-contractors/aca-enterprises-llc-0683-90029401,(850) 248-0597
https://www.bbb.org/us/fl/ponce-de-leon/profile/building-contractors/aca-enterprises-llc-0683-90029401,(850) 527-1767
https://www.bbb.org/us/nc/charlotte/profile/general-contractor/meyer-builders-llc-0473-219405,(704) 737-8409'''

for line in a.split('\n')[1:]: # Iterate through the string by each line, excluding the first line

    name = line.split('/')[-1] # The business name is the last substring in each line seperated by a slash

    name = re.findall('.*c(?=\-\d)',name) # .*c is the get all the characters behind c, including c. (?=something) will look forward to see if something is right in front of it. \-\d stands for a dash, and a digit

    print(name[0]) # The 0 is for getting the string, instead of the list
```

Output:

```
ag-builders-inc
russell-l-judy-builder-inc
russell-l-judy-builder-inc
aca-enterprises-llc
aca-enterprises-llc
meyer-builders-llc
```

Comment: Could you go into a bit of detail on how this was constructed and why it worked? I am trying to become more familiar with re and don't understand how the outcome was achieved.