# How to append data from a recurring function in a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary

I have a function which does the following computation and then saves the data in the dictionary. The function is called several time through a loop.

```
el_flip = self.element_flip(element_data)
    avg = np.array(el_flip[1])
    flip = np.array(el_flip[0])
   
    self.updated_element_data={}
    self.updated_element_data.update({})
    self.updated_element_data['avg'+self.elem_name+self.elem_path]=[avg]
    self.updated_element_data['flip'+self.elem_name+self.elem_path]=[flip]
    self.updated_element_data['orig'+self.elem_name+self.elem_path]=[element_data]

    print('dict',self.updated_element_data)
```

I tried using the update function, but it does not seem to help. I want each time this function is called, new values are computed and they should be added in the dictionary, rather they are over written.

Here, values for elem_name, elem_path, [avg,flip,element_data] change for each function call.

Comment: you always create a new empty dict when you call this code (lines 4 and 5), you want to do something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199171/append-multiple-values-for-one-key-in-a-dictionary)

Comment: oh yes, I am creating a new dict every time...thank you for the help.. :)