# How to create a dictionary with multiple values per key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary with multiple values in the form of a list for value of a key(To be precise for key '0').But when I use the zip function it is only giving the last updated value for that key instead of all values attached to that key.
Below is the **code**.

```
values_list = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
keys_list = [0,0,0,1,0,0,2,-1,0]
my_dict = dict(zip(keys_list, values_list))
print(my_dict)
```

**Output from above code:**

{0: [2, 2], 1: [1, 0], 2: [2, 0], -1: [2, 1]}

**Required Output:**

{0: [[0, 0],[0, 1],[0, 2],[1, 1],[1, 2],[2, 2]], 1: [1, 0], 2: [2, 0], -1: [2, 1]}

Comment: Your "Required Output" is not valid Python

Comment: "I want to create a dictionary with multiple values for value of a key" There is no such thing. But *as you have already observed*, a dictionary value can be a list, and a list can have multiple elements. Unfortunately, there is no "slick" way to build this structure - there are some helpers like `defaultdict` but fundamentally you will still have to iterate and append elements to the value lists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [append multiple values for one key in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199171/append-multiple-values-for-one-key-in-a-dictionary)

Comment: You should look into tree/graph.

Comment: @Don'tAccept No, I cannot relate to my question.

Comment: @Iain Shelvington May be there is something wrong with my explaination. But basically I want a list of mutliple values for a value of a particular key.(To be precise for key '0')

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, the format you asked isn't valid python (as it has entries without a key), but I believe the following works for you:

```python
values_list = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
keys_list = [0,0,0,1,0,0,2,-1,0]
my_dict = {}
for value, key in zip(values_list, keys_list):
    if key in my_dict:
        my_dict[key].append(value)

    else:
        my_dict[key] = [value]

print(my_dict)
```

which would output: `{0: [[0, 0, [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2]], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2]], 1: [[1, 0]], 2: [[2, 0]], -1: [[2, 1]]}`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to get '[0, 0],[0, 1],[0, 2]' form as value, It is impossible.

You sould cover [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2] with list or tuple.

list -> [ [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2] ]
tuple -> ( [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2] )

But still, you want to stay that form you can make it as str.
-> I don't recommend it. Because it will be hard to parse

Comment: May be there is something wrong with my explaination. But basically I want a list of mutliple values for a value of a particular key.(To be precise for key '0')

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `defaultdict`, you can yourself achieve similar to what `defaultdict` provides:
Don't create the dictionary directly from zip, instead iterate it and call `dict.get()` method with default value as empty list `[]`, and follow the logic.

```py
my_dict = dict()
for key,value in zip(keys_list, values_list):
    my_dict.update({key: my_dict.get(key, [])+[value]})
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
{0: [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2]], 1: [[1, 0]], 2: [[2, 0]], -1: [[2, 1]]}
```

All the values in Output will have nested list, *if you want to have nested list only for the keys which has more than one value*, you can first check if the key exists.